# How to switch to bash on DEVISH?

Tags: bash, shell

With the update from BasilOS Quad to Pentus, DEVISH became the primary shell(replacing bash). I need to be able to switch back to bash. I tried `chsh` but it said it was not a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply type `sh` to switch to an interactive bash shell... It was added as a feature for people who preferred Bash to DEVISH... Also, if you edit your .devishrc (found in ~), then you can add `DEVISH-func=false`, to permanently disable DEVISH... It is always reversible...

Answer (score 0):

Edit the user configuration to use bash as the default shell in the /etc/passwd file

```
vivek:x:1000:1000:vivek,,,:/home/vivek:/usr/local/bin/bash
```