# Which file should be sourced in .devishrc to permanently change the hitch-file?

Tags: shell, terminal

By default, in DEVISH (at least for me) the hitch file used is `mhitch.py`... I can change the hitch using the `-h` option for the `shfile` command, but I need to permanently set it to something.

Comment: Umm...  What are you talking about?

Comment: The DEVISH shell(default she'll on BasilOS Pentus)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a sample `.devishrc` would look something like this:

> `#!/bin/bash`
>   `#file:".devishrc"`
>   `# Ran by .bashrc, variables are interpreted by .devishrcint`
>   
>   `export func="true"`
>   `export hitch="/devish/info"`
>   `export start="" #does nothing`

I can see your confusion, changing `/devish/info` to whatever hitch you want it to be, and it throwing out errors every time you open the shell... the answer lies in the info file... The hitch, along with user aliases, are inside of the info file... a sample info file would look something like this:

> `#!/bin/bash`
>   `#file:"info"`
>   `# Includes hitch data and user aliases...`
>   
>   `export hitch="mhitch.py"`
>   
>   
>   `# User aliases:`

To select a different hitch, simply edit the `/devish/info` file, and change the `hitch` variable to whatever hitch program you want...

Comment: Thanks! With the update from Quad to Pentus, I was really confused, and there was almost no documentation on anything! Having DEVISH as the primary shell was a shocker... But I will get used to it... Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm...  @user120526: You might be interested in [How to switch to bash on DEVISH?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211380/80216)  … … … … … …  (Aren't search engines wonderful?)

Answer (score 0):

Building on what *Interesting...* said, you could always just delete the devish folder (`/devish`) by running `sudo rm -rf /devish` and then entering your password at the prompt. That is the messy way of permanently deleting DEVISH.

There **is** a cleaner way using the program (included with DEVISH) `devb`. To do this run `devb -r` which will **r**emove DEVISH and all of its related files.

I believe the variables in the `.devishrc` are variables are `func`, `hitch`, and `start` as opposed to `DEVISH-func`, `DEVISH-hitch`, and `DEVISH-start`.

Comment: I did have the wrong variables... those were the variables for an older version of DEVISH... Just updated my DEVISH and fixed my error ;)